# DBpedia: Few results only returned

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm using the following query to get Athletes data from DBpedia:

```
  SELECT * WHERE {

  ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> .
  ?player foaf:name ?firstname .
  ?player foaf:surname ?lastname .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?birthplace .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthDate .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/height> ?height .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/weight> ?weight .
}
```

but I only retrieve ~300 records back. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the last four as optional.